# SingularMatrixException when solving Linear EquationSystem

Tags: java, matrix, linear-algebra, ejml

I use EJML to solve a linear equation system.

> EJML uses doubles. My inputs (and expected outputs) are integers. I will omit the .000 from the toString().

My Matrix A looks like this (though it is ~1000x1000):

```
1  0  0  0  0
1 -1  1  0  0
0  1 -1  1  0
0  0  1 -1  1
0  0  0  0  1
```

My b is just a vector with a value in the first and the last index, the rest is 0.

```
{-10 0 0 0 10}'
```

For size 5x5 I can use EJML just fine, but for my 1000x1000 Matrix I get a `Solution contains uncountable numbers`-Error.

The result looks like this:

```
{NaN NaN NaN ... NaN -Infinity -Infinity 1}'
```

---

My code looks like this (the matrices are correct, I checked that via Sysout and Debugger):

```
// Setup A
// Setup b
SimpleMatrix x = A.solve(b);
```

---

Now I assume my System somehow behaves badly. Sadly I'm not that much into matrices, so I assume I'm maybe using the wrong methods to solve this particular problem. The other thing I can think of is that double-precision gets in my way.

Is there anything I can do or is EJML simply not the right tool here?

Comment: I've never used the tool but the *`NaN`* & *`Infinity`* come from *`1/0`* * *`0/0`*, this happens in the case of *zero determinant* , `D=0` , because the inverse of `A` is  `A^-1 = 1/D x A` , the D is zero happened before jumping into `X = A^-1 B` process.

Comment: Try looking at the singular values for the matrix.  I'm willing to bet there are some zeros in there.  That means that it's a singular matrix.  It lacks a unique solution.  There are an infinite number of solutions actually.  If that isn't a problem you can use SVD to select one of those many solutions.